# PHP form generation and validation standalone class

Tags: php, forms, webforms

I am looking for a form class that:

1. Is standalone/doesnt need a framework to run
2. Has easily configurable validation
3. Has validation and generation for all form fields including checkboxes(one solution I found was great except it didnt have any check box functionality)

I have had a look on google and stackoverflow but most everything I found was a year old, I am hoping in the last year something has been developed or improved.

My reason for asking is that I have a couple of very large forms to make that without a form class are going to take ages to build.  Unfortunatly I dont have time to develop my own class but I do have time to learn and use a recommended one as undoubtedly it will be far faster than writing hardcoded html forms with a PHP validation script.

I hope someone can help
Regards
Luke

UPDATE:

[Phorms](http://www.artfulcode.net/phorms/) has been fantastic, very simple to use syntax and very easy to bring into a project, the ability to set data for the form is great and also very simple to use, so great for a cms needing to edit articles etc.

UPDATE 2:

I wrote my own form class because Phorms did not allow for enough customising of html for me. [Nibble forms](http://nibble-development.com/nibble-forms-php-form-class) is hopefully very simple and easy to use.  I like it but I am a little bias :)

#### Update 3 (Feb 2013)

This has now evolved into [Nibble Forms 2](https://github.com/LRotherfield/Nibble-Forms) which uses PHP5.3 namespaces and conforms to the PSR 0,1 and 2 coding standards

Comment: coudl you tell us what the solution was that didn't have checkboxes? It sounds intersting (and could maybe be extended?)

Comment: Btw, you say that you had a look on google and stackoverflow - did you also check Source Forge?

Comment: I hadnt looked on source forge but just had a look but couldnt find much, the top results for "php form library" were xampp and wampserver

Comment: @LeonixSolutions I was looking at http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/phorms-a-php-form-library/ it does actually do checkboxes, I just hadnt found it, have you tried this library before? I would really like to use a recomended one.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I can't recommend one. I have been handrolling my own and whenever I repeat a task I look for ways to automate it. You post has refereshed my interst, so I will search and post whaetever I may find. If we can't find anything, then I may have to implement my own.

Comment: "php form library" - Found too many? SourceForge deafult is to find any of the words. Also try "PHP form generator" - I found http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpfgen/  but have not yet looked into it. Searching for "form generator gives 39 hits. Some obviously not relevant (not PHP), but enough for us to look into.

Comment: @LeonixSolutions, phorms has been great, see my above update.  Worth a go and a play

Comment: Phorms has a lot of bugs, not work for me! forget it, if you wanna something stable, do your own validation raw php is the best way, otherwise you will get a lot of headache, trying to fix this or that..  o_O

Comment: @Fernando Have you tried Nibble Forms, there is a link in the update 2 section of my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Phorms](http://www.artfulcode.net/phorms/) comes to mind, and it's lightweight.

The author of PHPClasses.org also has a very complete, altough somewhat blowated library.

Comment: +1 I like the look of this. However, although he defines many kinds of input fields - standards like edit, drop down & extras like email, phone numbers, etc, http://static.artfulcode.net/phorms/doc/elementindex_Fields.html doesn't seem to show support for radio buttons The sample code at http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/phorms-a-php-form-library/ seems clear enough, but he also admits that there is not much in the way of docs. I presume that validation is by field type, but I would also like more (perhaps min/max on integers). Still, it is definitely looks promising. Thanks

Comment: @LeonixSolutions: Then check this: http://freshmeat.net/projects/htmlformsgenerationandvalidation/, it's developed by Manuel Lemos, the author or PHPClasses.org. Examples at http://www.meta-language.net/forms-examples.html.

Comment: Looks like I will be using forms Alix, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: By forms I ment Phorms, has been great so far

Comment: The link is now a domain squat.

Answer (score 1):

Another recent project worth checking out is http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/. I have used this project in my development and would recommend.

Comment: I've used PHP Form Builder sometime but it hasn't any serious documentation. I've searched it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a standalone form library then Aura.Input is what you need.

I recently wrote how you can

integrate [Aura.Input](http://auraphp.com/Aura.Input) with [Aura.View](http://auraphp.com/Aura.View) helpers and create a standalone form( with code examples ) : http://harikt.com/blog/2013/05/23/standalone-form-for-php/

You can also integrate with any filtering library you like or with [Aura.Filter](http://auraphp.com/Aura.Filter) for a better validation , is over http://harikt.com/blog/2013/05/21/standalone-forms-and-validation/

The code examples are over github : https://github.com/harikt/phpform

Answer (score 0):

Check one of these : [Form-validation-library](https://github.com/webberty/Form-validation-library), [php-validation](https://github.com/blackbelt/php-validation/blob/master/Validator.php)